# Can I test tweakings of HTML/CSS intended for a Sharepoint solution in a non-Sharepoint solution?

Tags: html, css, sharepoint-2010, master-pages

We need to tweak some aspects of our Sharepoint site collection ("widen" the page, get rid of fixed/explicitly-sized elements).

I would like to test "probing" type changes in a separate environment, to quickly see what might work.

I have not been able to install Sharepoint on my dev machine (either at home or at work); we do the Sharepoint development via a Remote Desktop Connection to a Windows Server machine that has SP set up.

Anyway, what I'd like to do is create a "plain old" ASP.NET (not Sharepoint) app on my dev machine (locally) and test out my proposed HTML and CSS tweakings. Is this feasible and, if so, how?

Can I simply copy over the *.master pages (v4, minimal, default), the CSS files they reference and the HTML from various pages?

Is there a well-known way to test HTML/CSS changes for Sharepoint solutions in a non-Sharepoint solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "easy" way to do this as far as I know.

However there is a possible solution a bit more tricky.

You can convert an HTML page to a Sharepoint master page and so on.

See this link for info about HTML to Sharepoint

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822370.aspx

You could easily just reverse this process. i.e. Sharepoint to HTML

This would allow you to test however you would like. Then just apply changes accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If the majority of the changes you are making are CSS-based rather than HTML-based, you can do this with the inspector in a browser. FF is probably the easiest since it allows you to easily create and save a whole new stylesheet associated with a site that you're currently viewing. To do this:

1. Open FireFox.
2. Navigate to the SharePoint site.
3. Hit F12 or right-click on the page and choose Inspect Element.
4. In the inspector, go to the Style Editor tab.
5. Click New.
6. Start adding styles.
7. In the list of stylesheets on the left, find the new stylesheet that you've created and click "Save" next to it.
8. When you want to see the styles applied to another page in SharePoint, click Import next to the New button.

This works best if you have FireBug installed as well so you can inspect elements (to look at their applied styles and IDs/classes) separately from FireFox's inspector.